# get content from a list and run the Get-ADOrganizationalUnit for that list

Tags: list, powershell

I want to run the following script:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like `"*$OUs*`"" |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name
```

But I want to pass in a list of values for `$OU` from `c:\temp\list`

```
$OUs=c:\temp\list
foreach ($OU in OUs) {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like `"*$OUs*`"" |
        Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name  |
        Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\list.csv
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: And what keeps you from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code should work, given some typos are corrected:

```
$OUs = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\list.txt'

foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '*$OU*'" |
        Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName, Name |
        Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\list.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
}
```